# How to add placeholder with disabled value in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I need to add a placeholder with disabled value in an input field. What I'm doing wrong?

```
<?= $form->field($category, 'id')->dropDownList($categoryList, [
    'options' => ['id'=>'category-id'],
    'placeholder' => 'Select category', [
        'disabled' => true,
     ]
 ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $form->field($category, 'id')->dropDownList($categoryList, 
         [
              'id'=>'category-id',
              'prompt' => 'Select category', 

              // This is experimental
              'options' => [
                   '' => ['disabled' => true],
              ]
         ]
); ?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Placeholder haven't been added and `disabled` disables all the values

Comment: You have to use prompt attribute. I've edited the code.

Comment: But `disabled` still disables all the values, but I need it to disable just only `prompt`. I've tried to write it in `[ ]` brackets inside of `prompt`, but that didn't helped too

Comment: Placeholder is disabled by default. Why should you disable the placeholder?

Comment: I want to disable your `prompt`. It has to be disabled, because it's a `dependent drop-down list` and if I would choose prompt value, dep-drop list won't load any items

Comment: I've tried to ad experimental code, that I've not tested.

Comment: `prompt` value still isn't disabled. None of the values is disabled right now